# Multiple Queries with just one Recordset

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

Iam using ADODB to connect my Excel Macro to an Mysql Database. So far I always just connected, executed my Query and wrote the return in to my excel sheet.
But now I wanted to do multiple queries and write them into a sheet. How would I do something like that?
My preferred Solution would be something like:

- Open Connection
- SQLStatement = X
- Open Recordset with Statement
- Write Stuff in Sheet
- Close Recordset
- SQLStatement = Y
- Open Recordset with Statement
- Write Stuff in Sheet
- Close Recordset
- ..repeat a few times

The Following Code unfortunately isnt working. The first query is written in the sheet just fine but the second isnt, despite the Query yielding results when copied to mysql workbench. Nor Error Messages or anything.

```
SQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM ressourceplanning.projects ORDER BY Project_ID;"

Recordset.Open SQLStatement, Connection

Worksheets("Import").Cells(3, 1).CopyFromRecordset Recordset


Recordset.Close


SQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM ressourceplanning.orders ORDER BY Project_ID;"

Recordset.Open SQLStatement, Connection

Worksheets("Import").Cells(3, 9).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
```

I hope this isn't a duplicate but I honestly couldn't find an answer via searching.

Comment: What happens when you reverse the order? Is it always the second one that doesnt work? or is it always the orders one that doesnt work?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why your code shoudn't work. If you only execute the 2nd query, is it writing something?

Comment: Might be worth posting an answer and closing the query